# Decode json with dynamic line using PHP?

Tags: php, json, object, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

this is my code after json_decode:

```
stdClass Object (
    [batchcomplete] => 
    [query] => stdClass Object (
            [pages] => stdClass Object (
                    [56667] => stdClass Object (
                            [pageid] => 56667
                            [ns] => 0
                            [title] => Hanoi
                            [contentmodel] => wikitext
                            [pagelanguage] => en
                            [touched] => 2015-10-25T20:13:21Z
                            [lastrevid] => 687471695
                            [length] => 53648
                            [fullurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi
                            [editurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hanoi&action=edit
                            [canonicalurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How I can get values `[title]`, `[fullurl]` and `[pageid]` using PHP? I don't now how to go through line `[56667] => stdClass Object (` because `56667` is dynamic (it depends on request).

Comment: Pass the second parameter `true` within `json_decode($your_string,true)` and you'll get an array instead of objects. And I think you were aware of how to use arrays

Comment: @Uchiha _"And I think you were aware of how to use arrays"_ Not really, code sample would be handy.

Comment: Did you tried passing the second parameter within `json_decode`

Comment: This is how I understood your advice http://pastebin.com/PE8DMmDp and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reset()` to get the first array value. This will NOT require you to know the key.

Try this:

```
$output = json_decode($output, true); // convert to array so we can use reset.

$output_details = reset($output['query']['pages']);

$output_details['title']; // title
$output_details['fullurl']; // fullurl
$output_details['pageid']; // pageid
```

Comment: Nice, it worked too. I chose your answer because you wrote the code sample, thanks!